# OFFSET function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm having some trouble with the OFFSET function in Excel. I'm modifying a file created by someone else, the code was not written by me.

So in one sheet of the file, in the cells it applies the following formula that references another sheet in the file (Sheet Feb):

```
=IF(OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,0)=$B$2,OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,7),"")
```

Can someone help me better understand the logic of this formula. and particularly the `$A$2 + $A5` part, as I don't know what it means to add the cells in such a way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could show us the data, can you provide a few screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is `=OFFSET` (reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

So `OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,0)` means from reference cell `'Feb'!$A$1`, move `$A$2+$A5` rows down, i.e. take the contents of cell `$A$2` and `$A5` on the current sheet and sum them to obtain the rows offset, and then move than the number of rows down from `$A$1` on the 'Feb' worksheet

Then the value of this cell is compared with the contents of `$B$2` (on the current sheet). If they're the same, the value of `OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,7)` is returned otherwise 0

`OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,7)` is the value of the 7th column from `'Feb'!$A$1` on the same row calculated above.

`'Feb'!$A$1` is most likely the top left corner of a table with at least 7 columns, and the formula is trying to match a row of this table.

Comment: WD @David! @MOA Another detail to keep track of is the absolute references $A$1 and the relative ones without the $ sign. In `OFFSET('Feb'!$A$1,$A$2+$A5,0)` the reference cell is always fixed (top corner Feb sheet). The number of rows OFFSET looks downward from there (`$A$2+$A5`) has a constant offset `$A$2` that is the same for every row plus a relative offset `$A5` which will adjust to $A6 or $A7 as the formula is copied downward.

Comment: PS. The OFFSET formula is VOLATILE and will be dog slow in a large workbook. Try replacing it with `=IF(INDEX('Feb'!$A:$A,$A$2+$A5+1,0)=$B$2,INDEX('Feb'!$H:$H,$A$2+$A5+1,0),"")` or `=IF(INDEX('Feb'!$A:$A,$A$2+$A5+1,0)=$B$2,INDEX('Feb'!$A:$I,$A$2+$A5+1,8),"")`. The latter protects you against unintended column inserts in Feb sheet.

Comment: Yes INDEX / MATCH is a better pattern for table lookups, VLOOKUP is also often used but I believe it's volatile as well.